# Trying to add BigInt64 Item to listbox but getting Unable to cast object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have looked at the other posts and tried several suggestions but cannot figure this out.  I have to have a bigint column for our serial numbers but cannot cast them in the list box.  Following is the line of code that is giving me the issue:

```
 ListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)read2["IoTSerialNumber"]));

 I am getting this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to 
 type'System.String'.
```

As stated, I have to stay with bigint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains that you can't cast Int64 to string this way.
Try this:

```
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(read2["IoTSerialNumber"].ToString()));
```

**EDIT**: just in case: `ListBox.Items.Add` method takes strings only, this is why you should provide string representation of your number.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you Pavel...I always have problems with strings and int and that was so simple...much appreciated!

Comment: NP :)

Also check out reverse operation (string with big number to Int64):

`Int64.TryParse("some long number here", out long result)` (remember that C# 7 required for such inline declaration, otherwise you need to declare `result` before)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(read2["IoTSerialNumber"].ToString()));
```